# Deriving the PDF of extreme variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is: Suppose $X_1,...X_n$ are independent random variables from a continuous function with common $CDF$ $ F_Y(y)$ and common $PDF $ $f_X(x)$. Let $ Y= max \lbrace X_1,...X_2 \rbrace $. Now I showed in part a) that $ F_Y(y) = (F_X(y))^n$, but I am stuck on part b). Part b) asks me to derive the PDF, $f_Y(y) $. Any suggestions????

Answer (score 0):

$$f_y(y) = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{dy} = \frac{dF_X^n(y)}{dy} = n F_X^{n-1}(y) f_X(y)$$

Comment: But we had $ (F_X(x))^n $ on the right hand side which is in terms of x, not y... so do you just ignore the x and change it to y ?

Comment: @MathStudent You had it wrong. I fixed your question also. Otherwise the equation makes no sense - LHS in $y$ and RHS in $x$, but also the proof makes no sense either...

Comment: Are you sure? because this is what my professor posted :/

Comment: @MathStudent The argument for $F_Y(y)$ in terms of $F_X$ is only possible if they evaluate the same thing :) otherwise how can you draw any conclusions? What you are really saying is

$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]
       = \mathbb{P}[\max_{i=1}^n X_i \leq y]
       = \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}[X_i \leq y]
       = \prod_{k=1}^n F_X^n(y) = F_X^n(y).
$$

Comment: You have convinced me lol so I'll have to let my prof know. Thank you.

Comment: Oh one more question, how should I go about finding the $ PDF$ for $f_X(x) $? Would it be the same thing but in terms of $X$'s?

Comment: @MathStudent Yes, $f_X(x) = F_X'(x)$.

Comment: So $f_X(x) = nf_X(x)(F_X(x))^{n-1} $???

Comment: @MathStudent no!!! $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(x)$ are different functions! But you get it a similar way - pdf is the derivative of the cdf, so $f_X(x) = F'_X(x)$.

Comment: That's what I'm confused with, how do we find the cdf?

Comment: @MathStudent Your question implies CDF is given to you.

Comment: It's not. I typed the entire question above :(

Comment: @MathStudent The question does NOT ask for pdf of $X$, which we called $f_X(x)$. It asks for pdf of $Y$, which we called $f_Y(y)$, which I showed you how to derive in my answer.

Comment: Part c is asking for the joint pdf, which I need the pdf of $X$ for. That's why I only asked that part because I know since they are independent its just the product of the two pdfs.